# how much pages do i have for a paperback book

Tags: fiction, mystery, thriller

I'm making a book and I already wrote 54,099 and 278,889 characters how much pages do I have for a paper back or hard back book

Comment: Heya! Welcome to Writers.SE! We've previously addressed this question, so I'm closing this post, and the existing answers should help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the size of the page, the margins, and the font.

Print a page or two in the format you want, or find a book in that format, and count the number of characters per page. Then divide your total number of characters by that number and you'll have your answer.